# Parallel Foreach sometimes getting stuck/freeze

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

So my parallel foreach sometimes gets stuck and when debugging I try break all to see where I'm at and it's always on the beginning of the parallel foreach.
It doesn't do it every time but when it does it , it's after a while.

Can you guys help me out figure it out? I don't really understand why beside the fact that it could be because every threads are accessing the list of checkedPogos

```
public static Task<List<string>> Checks(List<string> pogos)
{
    arret = false;

    var pogoTask= new Task<List<string>>(() =>
    {
        List<string> checkedPogos= new List<string>();
        Parallel.ForEach(pogos, (string pogo, ParallelLoopState state) =>
        {
                if (arret)
                    state.Stop();
                pogo= pogo.Trim();
                if (pogo != null && Check(pogo))
                {
                    checkedPogos.Add(pogo);
                }
        });
        return checkedPogos.Distinct().ToList();
    });
    pogoTask.Start();
    return pogoTask;
}
```

EDIT : I've changed the List to a concurrent collection and it still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Lists are not threadsafe. You should use a concurrent collection. I suggest using a concurrentbag. 

https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=concurrentbag%20c%23&oq=concurrentbag%20c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2209j0j7

Comment: @gnicholas that should fix it?

Comment: Yes, it will.  Though if this code is for IA64 you need the arret variable to be marked volatile.

Comment: Changing to a concurrent collection may or may not fix the freeze, but you need to fix it anyway.

Comment: It is a starting point. You didn't post all of your code. I have no idea what Check(pogo) does. In fact in can do anything!  I'm assuming it somehow modifies the value of arret otherwise arret would never be modified. If it does modify arret, then as hoodaticus suggested you need to mark it volatile or put a lock around it.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it ( took 1 second ), will update with how it goes !

Comment: Your `pogo != null` check is pointless, it would have thrown a `NullRefrenceException` on `pogo.Trim();` if the string was null.

Comment: Lists aren't thread safe, and you'll find this out when it throws oddball exceptions when different threads manipulate it.  The type doesn't check for reentrancy, it just breaks in odd ways.  I've seen it a hundred times, but I've never seen it cause a *deadlock*.  I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @Will so how would i fix this? i've tried concurrent collection and still not working properly

Comment: Your Check method is suspicious. Change its content to something trivial like add some local variables and return. If the problem is gone, you will know the trouble is in your original Check. What does Check do anyway?

Comment: This just seems way over-complex for what it does.  Not sure if you've removed some lines that actually do work that is time-intensive.  Get rid of the parallel.foreach and run it single threaded.  Or, split up the list yourself into n chunks and feed them into n tasks.  Then return a task that awaits them all.